# In a City, Are Sewers and Garbage Heaps Usually Connected?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, apocalypse, near-future, construction

I am making a semi-apocalyptic world in the near future in which there is a main, thriving city, around which there are scavengers who dig through the garbage as well as hang around the open sewer system. Would the sewers and garbage dumps be near each other?

Comment: I can't understand the question. Garbage dump is one place. Sewer, on the other hand, is everywhere in the city, as it's purpose is to take wastewater from the city and transport it elsewhere. Sewer may pass near a garbage dump, but it can't be just "placed there". Maybe you're asking about sewage treatment plant?

Comment: It's up to you, and the city planners, to decide where the sewers lead to

Comment: Welcome to the site, ZIMF! Your question is a little unclear. What style of city are you considering? What does the terrain look like? Could you clarify what you mean by the sewers being near landfills? Adding these details should prevent your question from being closed as unclear, but that is the future I see as it stands.

Comment: Usually cities forbid garbage heaps, dumps and landfills, they are in the country.

Comment: You can't hang out in a sewer system; you're thinking stormwater system.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity's sake:

- The sewer is a network of pipes typically under streets connecting to buildings; usually sewerage is gravitational, with pump stations where necessary.  All that sewage ends up in a sewage treatment plant.
- The garbage dump is where trash is taken by trucks far outside / downwind of town.

---

The pipes you want your dudes to hang out in are **NOT** sewage pipes, you are thinking of stormwater drainage pipes, which can be big enough to hang out in, and drain (typically) downhill to a river or the sea.

These are not always treated, and the only reason they smell bad is because bad stuff washes down into them.  These are accessed by drains in the curb and manholes in the city have ladders down into them.  The largest ("stormwater mains") are typically found under the main streets, and they're the ones you see people walking about in movies.

For your story's sake, I don't think you'd find the stormwater pipes near a garbage dump because of contamination.  However, you most certainly can have people in both places.  Garbage dump populace *outside* of town and stormwater populace *inside* town (you can still call them sewers, if you like, but you might mention that you know they're not actually sewers).

Answer (score 0):

That sort of depends if your setting is more post-apocalyptic or post-industrial.  One is based on fantasy (or religion) but may include a natural disaster, and tends to focus on re-building or preserving ways that once where.  Post-industrial is a more entropic endstate of civ, and experiments with either a revival of primitivism or the adaptations of society as non-renewable resources dwindle.  A rejection of the oldways.  This distinction helps shape the evolution of your city and determines how well organized are your denizens, how they extract or pillage resources from their surroundings (because cities cannot sustain themselves), and what they do with refuse.  In either case you're also not likely to have the industrial base for production of wasteful goods, so residence of your city are not likely to produce garbage.  Most of refuse will likely be compostable anyhow and likely to ben simply be 'washed' away because how likely is it to still have city services, dumpsters, and trash collection?  So yes, waste could be mixed with sewage, but only if NOBODY in your entire city has a decent garden with the need for compost.

Also, people tend to avoid sewage.  I don't understand why you would have people 'hanging' around the sewer system, people don't do that except in modern cities where police like to hassle the homeless and force them to seek shelter in drainages.

Garbage is only a product of wasteful capitalist and industrial societies and such societies is not likely to survive any apoc scenario.  In-fact, their destruction is why people embellish postapoc settings in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your futuristic city has a futuristic rubbish collection system that, instead of having trucks come around and empty the bins, rubbish is "flushed away" and transported to the dump through underground tunnels and channels just like sewerage. For convenience of building and maintenance, sewerage and rubbish channels run together (like telegraph poles with roads or railways in modern times).

Therefore your scavengers have a good reason to hang out in the sewers.